# how to prevent rounding my number automatically in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, auto

am want to divide  99999999999999999 on 100000 the answer is 9999999.9999999999‬ but python is auto rounding it to 1000000000000.0

```
>>> 99999999999999999/100000
1000000000000.0
```

[Here's how is it shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RR6w.png)

Comment: This is not (just) Python, this is [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) math.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Decimal`

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(99999999999999999)/Decimal(100000)
Decimal('999999999999.99999')
```